# Android MediaRecorder start failed in invalid state 4

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediarecorder

I try to record the audio, only the audio, and I get this error on android 4.1.2 but not on 4.3:

Here is the code:

```
private void startRecord(){
    on_record = true;
    final boolean exists = (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + NOTAY)).exists();
        if (!exists) {new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Test").mkdirs();}

        final boolean existAud = (new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + NOTAY + File.separator + "Audio")).exists();
        if (!existAud) {new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Test" + File.separator + "Audio").mkdirs();}

        final EditText editTitle= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
        final String title = editTitle.getText().toString();
        final String audioName = getDate(System.currentTimeMillis()).replaceAll(" ", "_");
        currentAudioPath =    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Test"
                            + File.separator
                            + "Audio"
                            + File.separator
                            + System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + audioName + ".3gpp";

        if(title.length() == 0)
            editTitle.setText(audioName);

        Recorder = new MediaRecorder();

        Recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        Recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        Recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        Recorder.setOutputFile(currentAudioPath);


        try {
            Recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        Recorder.start();

    }

    private void saveRecord(){

        Recorder.stop();
        Recorder.release();
        Recorder = null;
        on_record = false;

        currentAudioPath = NO_AUDIO;

    }
```

And here the logs:

```
10-24 08:34:02.777: E/MediaRecorder(13491): start called in an invalid state: 4
10-24 08:34:02.777: D/AndroidRuntime(13491): Shutting down VM
10-24 08:34:02.777: W/dalvikvm(13491): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e5b440)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491): java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.androtest.audio.startRecord(AudioActivity.java:357)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.androtest.audio.onOptionsItemSelected(AudioActivity.java:307)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
10-24 08:34:02.823: E/AndroidRuntime(13491):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've read hundreds of thread on this error but I can't find anything that solves my issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I find out what was my problem.
This:

```
final String audioName = getDate(System.currentTimeMillis()).replaceAll(" ", "_");
```

Return a string that contains this character: ":"
Replacing it by:

```
final String audioName = (getDate(System.currentTimeMillis()).replaceAll(" ", "_")).replaceAll(":", "-");
```

Solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and solved it by fixing the path of the file. So if you have invalid state 4, **check if you have output file path set and if it really exists**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call reset after initializing Recorder

```
     Recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            Recorder.reset();
            Recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            Recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
            Recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            Recorder

.setOutputFile(currentAudioPath);


        try {
            Recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        Recorder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and then realized the path to my output file was incorrect.  Correcting the path solved my issue.